# IIS 8.5 becomes unresponsive until iisreset, no indication of issue

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5, asp.net-mvc

I have a web app which is load balanced across two Windows 2012 R2 servers with IIS 8.5. Sometimes, it seems the IIS process gets "stuck" on one web server but there is no indication of an issue anywhere - not in our app logs or the Windows event log. The only thing which fixes it is an iisreset. And the only way we know it's happening is because the site fails to load intermittently and we get email alerts.

How can I catch these events without relying on monitoring alerts? I want to configure an HTTP probe on the load balancer but that means the web server will be silently removed from rotation and we'll have no idea that a web server has an issue.

Comment: Your problem is the webapp that corrupt the app pool IMO, can you code a health check for your webapp ? I would do that and the http probe like you told.

Comment: I agree the issue ultimately lies in the code, and I have raised this with the dev team but good luck getting that fixed any time soon. My concern is that if we put an HTTP health probe, the server will be silently removed from the rotation, and we can't check each server individually since external traffic has to pass through the load balancer.